# Can I use Cloudflare Workers to batch requests?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I would like to log requests made to my site which travel through Cloudflare. I think I can use Cloudflare Workers to do this, but I don't want to DoS my logging service by making a request to it with every request made to my site. Can I have the Worker bundle the logging reports up and only make a request to me with every 10 or 100?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, yes you can do this! You have to use `event.waitUntil` to add a task which will run after the original request has been responded to. The one bug with this is if the Worker script gets evicted from memory, we will lose our `batchedRequests`, but that doesn’t seem to happen very often.

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(fetchAndLog(event))
})

let batchedRequests = []

function sendRequests(){
  let promises = []
  for (var i=batchedRequests.length; i--;){
    promises.push(fetch(...batchedRequests[i]))
  }

  batchedRequests = []

  return Promise.all(promises)
}
/**
 * Fetch and log a given request object, uploading a logging request only when five are stored
 * @param {Request} request
 */
async function fetchAndLog(event) {
  batchedRequests.push(["https://hookb.in/Kb88Ybq8", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      timestamp: +new Date
    })
  }])

  if (batchedRequests.length > 4){
    event.waitUntil(sendRequests())
  }

  return fetch(event.request)
}
```